# Hspice mode of a Lossy Transmission line

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, analog, transmission-line, microwave

Can someone provide a HSPICE model of a lossy Transmission line which I can simulate in Cadence virtuoso or Synopsys custom compiler?
I need lossy Transmission line model for Z0=50ohm and length =10inch for a FR4 Material

Comment: Doesn't cadence provide a model that you can enter the L, C, G and R values?

Comment: Yeah the whole point of cadence is that it brings these models. So, you just need to enter the parameters of your lossy transmission line in the... Transmission line model.